# How to remove Android auto-suggest underlining in EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I'm using an EditText to write some text. Android's auto-suggest underlines the word, until we hit space. Now, if I enter the word without the space, the resulting text has an underline. It's because I use `Html.toHtml(view.getText())`.

Now, there are a few answers I'll be expecting such as disabling auto-suggestion or using `view.getText().toString()`, but I need them both. I need the auto-suggestion feature as well as the formatting of the text. An example which solves this problem is the Gmail app. You can write whatever you want in the EditText box and it sends the email without the words being underlined.

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong, but the red line thing is part of the auto-suggestion feature. How can you want the auto suggest but not the red line?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy When I'm typing something in the EditText box, I want the auto suggestions. But when I parse the text in HTML, I don't want the underline styling because of that feature. I found it really weird that parsing that text captures the underline because I thought that would be a low level feature. Now I want to get rid of that, without hampering any other formatting of text in the EditText box, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this just before you getText(). **This is the most straightforward and the official way**.

```
 edittext.clearComposingText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Like I said, I do want to use the auto suggest feature. Disabling that would get rid of the underline, but remove the feature too.

Comment: This would disable the text suggestion feature altogether just for disabling the underline.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with a solution for this. After submitting the text, just hide the keyboard, and the text underline goes away.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly you did it? Because though I run the hide keyboard function first and secondly the from html function the second command runs before the first one is completed. (I can press a button and disable the keyboard (this removes underline) and  then press a key again to get the content as html. But how can I do both in single click? Is there a way to disable keyboard so that the next line would run only after the keyboard hiding and all is completed?)

Comment: This was long back but I think I faced a similar issue so I made the thread sleep for a couple of milliseconds. Not the best way to do it, but I couldn't find a better solution then. @SadeepDarshana posted a good solution, so I marked it as the accepted answer.