# EditText clearComposingText in TextWatcher (Need to remove autocorrect underline in Android OS 4.4)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I'm trying to do something similar to this post ([How to remove Android auto-suggest underlining in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992048/how-to-remove-android-auto-suggest-underlining-in-edittext)) where I want to remove the underline while the user is typing. I am making a rich text editor and do not want the autocomplete underlines to be confused with the underlines that are part of the rich text.

I have a RichTextEditor (which is a rich text editor that extends AppCompatEditText) and with an inner RichTextEditorTextWatcher class. I am doing `RichTextEditor.this.clearComposingText()` each time the user types, because I do not want to see the underline while the user is typing.

Issue: When I remove the `MyEditText.this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);` line, every time the user types, the entire word suggestion is appended as part of any input, which is totally wrong.

e.g. when I type "A", then "d", then "e", I get "AAdAde" in the edit text.

Putting `RichTextEditor.this.clearComposingText();` in `beforeTextChanged` doesn't work either.

What I need is the autocomplete underline removed, with other behavior preserved (i.e. I need textMultiline etc as in my inputType attribute in the XML).

How can I fix this?

**NOTE**: This problem of the autocomplete underline appearing is only occurring in OS 4.4 (Samsung Galaxy S4). The         `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` seems to have no effect on this version of Android, whereas it works on later versions of Android.

```
public class RichTextEditor extends AppCompatEditText
{


    public class RichTextEditorTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable e)
        {
            //other implementation not shown here
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
             RichTextEditor.this.clearComposingText();
             RichTextEditor.this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        }
    }
```

}

```
<com.my.app.RichTextEditor android:id="@+id/rich_text_editor"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textLongMessage|textNoSuggestions"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I have tried the suggestions here: http://charlesharley.com/2011/programming/disabling-android-textview-suggestions but they don't work on Samsung Galaxy S4. i.e., the following do not work:

`<TextView android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />`
`<TextView android:inputType="textFilter" />`